# How to remove index using a button SWIFT

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, button, indexing

I would like to know how to remove an Index from an Array using a button? Can i use the "@IBAction func name(sender: UIButton)" or do I have to use something else? Please let me know, I'm still a noob to swift.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelText: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var label0: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var shoppingList = ["eggs", "milk", "cake", "sugar"]

        labelText.text? = "you are missing \(shoppingList.count) items"


        if shoppingList.count > 0 {
            label0.text = shoppingList[0]
        } else {
            label0.text = "empty"
        }

        if shoppingList.count > 1 {
            label1.text = shoppingList[1]
        } else {
            label1.text = "empty"
        }

        if shoppingList.count > 2 {
            label2.text = shoppingList[2]
        } else {
            label2.text = "empty"
        }

        if shoppingList.count > 3 {
            label3.text = shoppingList[3]
        } else {
            label3.text = "empty"
        }


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Wow... you need a table view...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an input for which item in the array you would like to remove.  You can use a textfield for the input and a button for the submit.  In this case you would use the button IBAction as an indicator to get the index from the textfield. Then remove the index with

```
shoppingList.removeAtIndex(indexToBeRemoved)
```

`var shoppingList = ["eggs", "milk", "cake", "sugar"]` should be declared as a property of the class to be accessible within the member functions.

Comment: This is correct, but the OP has some other issues, such as `shoppingList` being a local variable

Comment: Good Point!  The variable must be in scope.  Make it a property of the View Controller.